# Libgdx rotate ModelInstance

Tags: java, matrix, 3d, rotation, libgdx

I am developing my first libgdx 3D game. Until now i can move arround in a maze-like (hardcoded) world, collision detection works. Also i have some enemies with working A* Pathfinding.
I also loded my first (pretty ugly) Blender model, using `FBX-Conv` to get a `.g3db` file. For some reason the model lise on the floor instead of standing. Maybe i had some wrong settings when i exported it as `.fbx`.
For that i tryed to `rotate()` him arround the `z-Axis` by `90` degrees by calling:
`modelInstance.transform.rotate(Vector3.Z, 90)` in the `show()` method of my `Screen`, after loading the `Model` and instantiating my `ModelInstance` (at a given position). For some reason it did not rotate. Then i put the `rotate` method in the `render(delta)`, thinking, that it would now rotate 90 degrees every render loop. But instead it was standing still, like it should.
Okay, but now i want the `modelInstance` to `rotate` to where it actually looks, meaning it should rotate, depending on my `enemie`s `Vector3 direction`.
I am allready setting his position with `modelInstance.transform.setTotranslation(enemie.getPosition())` which works perfect. So i thought i can also use `modelInstance.transform.setToRotation(Vector3 v1, Vector3 vs)`, with `v1 = enemie.getPosition()` and `v2 = enemie.getPosition().add(enemie.getDirection)`. Note, that the `position` Vector is not used directly, as it would change its values inside the `add()` method.
Doing this, i don't see the object anymore, meaning also its position is wrong.

Why is this happening?
And how can i rotate my `modelInstance` by using the `direction` vector?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Matrix4#rotate does rotate (post multiplies) the matrix. So you might want to include some code to show the problem. You also probably want to rotate -90 degrees on the X axis (not Z axis), or better yet check the export to FBX settings in your modeling application, see also: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Importing-Blender-models-in-LibGDX#setting-the-coordinate-system-up-axis Use Matrix4#setToRotation(Vector3, Vector3) or rotate(Vector3, Vector3) to rotate using a direction, where one vector is the direction and the other is face side of the model (e.g. Vector3.Z).

Comment: @Xoppa Okay thanks again i will try that with the 2 `Vecotr3`s. I think i missunderstood them, cause i thougt, that one `Vector3` is the object position and one is the target position (pos.add(direction)). If it does not work i will post the code. Thanks

Comment: @Xoppa i think it works now. I did not see, that `Matrix4.setToTranslation()` does not only set the `position` of the `ModelInstance`, but does also set it to an identity matrix first. At the moment my `ModelInstances` only look to front, back, left, right and so i am not sure if it really works, but i think it does. I will make another test soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with @Xoppas help. The problem was:

1. i used `setToTranslation` to move my `Model` to a given position, but this als resets the `rotation`
2. I missunderstood the `setToRotation(Vector3, Vector3)` method.

So the solution was to to the `setToTranslation` first, and then use `setToRotation(Vector3 direction, Vector3 face)`, where `direction` is the direction, in which my `Model` is looking and `face` is the `face`, which should look in this direction, in my case the `Vector3.X`.

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Worse case scenario, you could modify the transformation matrix using:

```
ModelInstance.transform.rotate()
```