# libgdx ModelInstance translating and rotating don't work

Tags: libgdx

My problem is i have a model (g3db) and

```
touchPosition.x = Gdx.input.getX();
        touchPosition.y = Gdx.input.getY();
        rotation.y = (float) Math.atan2(touchPosition.x - Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, touchPosition.y - Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees + 90;
        shipInstance.transform.translate(-10, 0, 0);
        shipInstance.transform.setToRotation(new Vector3(0,1,0),rotation.y);
```

the ship is only rotating but not moving in the space.
What did i wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380807/libgdx-rotate-modelinstance and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837736/libgdx-how-to-rotate-a-3d-model-on-multiple-axes-with-phone-orientation

Comment: i have modified it a bitshipInstance.transform.setFromEulerAngles(rotation.y, 0, 0);
   shipInstance.transform.translate(-10,0,0);                                               But there is still no traslatio